# hdfc bank net banking page not accessible

Tags: firefox, chromium

Whenever I try to open the website **www.hdfcbank.com**, the website opens. Then I check the **netbanking** box and press the **login** tab below. A new window opens up as it is supposed to, but in the new window, there is an option which says **continue to netbanking**. When this is pressed, my browser should direct me to a page which asks for my customer id, but nothing happens. It seems as if the tab is unresponsive. I tried it on firefox as well as chromium, but the results are the same. I'm guessing it's got something to do with some package on Ubuntu. Kindly help. Btw, I'm using Saucy 13.10.

Additionally, if I am trying to make a transaction online via hdfc bank netbanking, then the merchant site should directly link to my customer id page and in that case the merchant site returns an error saying that the website is down or the page is unavailable. Please help.

Comment: I think that the website from the merchant site is already giving you all the information. This does not sound at all like a browser or package error, but rather that the site is actually down. The reason it seems unresponsive is because the website isn't sending anything back, in other words its down. In which case I recommend trying another time when the site is back up

Comment: no, the site wasn't down because this always happens, I have never been able to open that page using ubuntu, whereas it always opens using windows

Comment: @DKBose Could you tell me how to rectify that? Is it a cookie problem or anything?

Comment: okay. Let me check...

Comment: I tried using a new profile but to no avail. Still doesn't work. Is it a problem with my Java reader or HTML reader?

Comment: Write the bank and tell them you are switching banks because they do not support Linux and find another bank.